# How to add a parameter to a submit action in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form with an action defined on submit. 
I would like to have two buttons that submit the form with a parameter. 
Here is an example:

```
<form {{action "doStuff" on="submit"}}>
    <input type="text">
    ....
    ....
    <button type="submit">Do Stuff</button>
    <button type="submit">Do Stuff and Other Stuff</button>
</form>

doStuff(doOtherStuff=false){
    //do stuff
    if(doOtherStuff){
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

I know I can define two actions on the buttons like this :

```
<button type="submit" {{action "doStuff" false}}>Do Stuff</button>
<button type="submit" {{action "doStuff" true}}>Do Stuff and Other Stuff</button>
```

But I would like to befit from the form submission (HTML validation, etc)

Is this something possible, or am I missing something big ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass argument required value or property to action helper like the below,

```
{{action "doStuff" true on="submit"}}
```

You can get it from doStuff functions,

```
doStuff(isEnabled){
  //do common stuff
  if(isEnabled){
  //do enable stuff
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Option1) We can do like `<form onsubmit={{action "doStuff"}}>` and inside `doStuff` you will get `event` object as first argument, but then again we are not able to differentiate which button is called. so solution would be like use if block helper to include one at a time.

Option2) Use isFirst boolean property to differentiate,

[Sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2b129fe5c4988b01540ba963c8ccab88?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) to demonstrate

application controller,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isFirst: false,
  actions:{
    doStuff(event){
      console.log('isFirst',this.get('isFirst'));      
      return false;
    },
    setIsFirst(val){
      this.set('isFirst',val);
    }
  }
});
```

application.hbs

```
<form onsubmit={{action "doStuff"}}>
   <button type="submit" id="test1" value="first" {{action 'setIsFirst' true preventDefault=false}}>firstbutton</button>
   <button type="submit" id="test2" value="second" {{action 'setIsFirst' false preventDefault=false}}>second button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean in the helper in the form tag?  I get that, but if I want to do a different action depending on the button used, how does it help ?

Comment: Do you want to display both button at the same time, if not we can use if block helper to display one at a time.

Comment: @hereismass I updated my answer with possible options. i think option2 is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, the second option is what I was looking for. Thanks :)